# Sprinkler Example, how to compute probabilities?

Tags: probability, bayesian, bayesian-network

[image]

Can you explain how do you compute probabilities like, P(S=F|C=T)  and P(W=F|S=F,R=T) ?

Comment: It looks as though you read them directly off the tables given. For example, p(S=F|C=T)=0.9 from the bottom left of the leftmost table. p(W=F|S=F,R=T)=0.1 from the penultimate line of the bottom table.

Comment: In this video between 21:40 and 22:00, Nando de Freitas says if you don't understand the probability of P(W=0)|S=0,R=1), you are lost, Does he mean to compute it by using marginalization and conditioning or does he mean to understand it intuitively? - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xhdpk9HZQuo&index=7&list=PLE6Wd9FR--Ecf_5nCbnSQMHqORpiChfJf

Comment: Worrying. As far as I  can see, he asked them to read values off a table and some couldn't after 3 min discussion with their neighbours! They did not have to understand anything!